# Crystal report image shaded in black

Tags: image, crystal-reports, report

I was facing the issue on crystal report in window server 2003 with IIS6 environment, whereby the image was shaded in black, and the image was in JPG format, it was running fine on the developer server. does this happened before for yours?

Comment: Try converting the JPG to a 256-bit BMP. Crystal sometimes doesn't play nice with other formats, especially when they're printed or exported.

Comment: will try this on clients server tomorrow, beside of this, is there any others possibility?

Comment: already convert from JPG to a 256-bit BMP, but the image still appear in black.. any ideas?